# Getting error while installing any module using "pip install ..." in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip

While updating python from v3.8.6 to 3.9, I just got complications so I uninstalled Python and Visual Studio Code. I also removed every file and folder associated with python and VS code from my Local Disk C ( I hope I haven't removed something important while doing so) and also everything from Registry Editor. In short, from my side, I made my computer as if python and VSC were never installed there.
Then I again installed the "Latest" versions of both python (3.9) and Visual Studio Code (1.49.3). But when I tried to install different packages i.e. numpy, Pillow etc. on my CMD, I got complicated list of errors.
I have searched for the solution everywhere but I am unable to solve my issue. Actually I am unable to know the reason of errors, hence I am unable to search for the related solution.
The images of my cmd showing errors is hereby attached.
[image: Cmd showing error -1]

[image: Cmd showing error -2]

Comment: What do you not understand about your python `version 3.9` not being supported?

Comment: @Compo Sorry, I am unable to get what you are saying.

Comment: Did you "[Please see the install instructions at:…](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)"?

Comment: @Compo this issue is not just related with pillow, infact this error is occurring for every module i am trying to install

Comment: You supplied specific screenshots for installing pillow, and it is evident that you're using python v3.9 and pillow v7.2, which are not a recommended combination! _You said that you did not get what I was saying, so I tried to tell you in another way!_

Comment: Actually I am receiving same error for every module e.g. numpy, pygame, pillow etc. So I shared the screenshots just to show the type of error.

Comment: Python 3.9 is only **just been released**, and many projects have yet to build a binary wheel. See the duplicate for a work-around, because there are alternative sources for binary wheels for Windows (which have been building those wheels early)

Comment: And yes, Pillow has been build already: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow, so use `pip install pipwin` then `pipwin install Pillow` and you should be all set.

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html

Comment: @Hugo what about other packages e.g.numpy, pygame etc?

Comment: NumPy are waiting for Azure Pipelines to add 3.9 so they can build wheels. It's due early this coming week. See  https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1740#issuecomment-709382218 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17482